# Jasmine test with angularjs $resource fails because of timeout

Tags: angularjs, testing, resources, promise, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to understand how to work with async functions in Jasmine, so I've made a simple test:

```
    describe('Promise testing', function() {
        beforeEach(module('task6'));

        var $rootScope, $resource;

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$resource_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $resource = _$resource_;
        }));

        it('tests $resource queries', function(done) {
            $resource('users.json').query().$promise
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('users');
                    expect(false).toBe(true);
                    done();
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    console.log('Error');
                    done();
                });
            $rootScope.$digest();
        });
    });
```

And it always fails with an "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."
the users.json file is in the same folder with the test.
Why is it failing? :)